# How to Count number of files in AWS S3 Server using python script and boto3 library

Tags: python, amazon-s3, automation, boto3, python-3.10

I am trying to write a script in python that will go to **AWS S3 Bucket** link and count how many files there are. There are a lot of files but I only want to count files who's name start with `file_`. These files are incremental in nature. On top of that I also have to transverse the folder as there files are chunk of a video so I also want to transverse quality and check their chunk count too.

Path would be like: `s3://url/144p/`

In this path there will be chunks that needed to be count.

I used boto3 library. Coming up is my code:

```
import csv
import boto3

# Base S3 URL
base_s3_url = 's3://coursevideotesting/'  # Replace this with your base S3 URL

# Input and output CSV file names
input_csv_file = 'ldt_ffw_course_videos_temp.csv'  # Replace with your input CSV file name
output_csv_file = 'file_count_result.csv'  # Replace with your output CSV file name

# Function to count 'file_000.ts' objects in a specific S3 folder
def count_file_objects(s3_bucket, s3_folder):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=s3_folder)

    # Count 'file_000.ts' objects in the folder
    count = sum(1 for obj in response.get('Contents', []) if obj['Key'].startswith('file_000.ts'))
    return count

# Read URLs from input CSV and check file counts
with open(input_csv_file, mode='r') as infile, open(output_csv_file, mode='w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    fieldnames = ['URL', 'Actual Files', 'Expected Files']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        s3_url = base_s3_url + row['course_video_s3_url']  # Replace 'URL_Column_Name' with your column name
        expected_files = int(row['course_video_ts_file_cnt'])  # Replace 'Expected_Files_Column_Name' with your column name
        actual_files = count_file_objects('coursevideotesting', s3_url)  # Replace 'your-s3-bucket-name' with your bucket name
        
        writer.writerow({'URL': s3_url, 'Actual Files': actual_files, 'Expected Files': expected_files})
```

What I recieved:

```
URL,Actual Files,Expected Files
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,0,28
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,0,34
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,0,54
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,0,57
```

What I expected:

```
URL,Actual Files,Expected Files
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,28,28
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,34,34
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,52,54
s3://coursevideotesting/.../144p/,57,57
```

Actual file being less than actual in case of missing file/corruption. So that I can directly work on those chunks instead of manually checking everyone of those. I have 5 quality types and several chunks in each folder.

Output for `print("Response: ",response.get('Contents'))`
Checking the Folder in this is just checking weather path is right or wrong. In this path, there are file_000.ts, file_001.ts and so on that I want to count.

```
Checking folder: s3://coursevideotesting/Financial_Freedom_Course_Kannada/00_Course_Trailer_New_update/360p/
Response:  None
Actual chunks found: 0
```

As for `print(response['Contents'])` it throws an error.

Comment: It would appear that your `count_file_objects()` function is not behaving as you expect. I suspect it is due to `if obj['Key'].startswith('file_000.ts')` because the Key of an object is the full path, including the directory name. I recommend that you add a `print(response['Contents'])` line to view what boto3 is returning to your program.

Comment: Also, be aware that `list_objects_v2` is a paginated API, returning at most 1000 objects.  If any prefix will ever contain more than 1000 objects, then you'll need to [paginate through the responses](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I used `print(response['Contents'])` it returned none as output. When I used `print(response)` in the count file function and got a separate response. A complex dict which had `ResponseMetadata`. I'm struck at this problem for few days now.

Comment: Please Edit your question and show the result of `print(response)` command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added what you have asked. I printed every value possible in my code to troubleshoot my problem. I am getting `response.get('Contents')` as None which is why it's not counting the actual chunks present in AWS S3. I will search more to get to the crux of this problem.

Comment: If you use `print(response)` and can confirm that there is no `Contents` element, then it means that there are no objects that match your request. Specifically, I'd say that `s3_folder` does not contain a valid value. Make sure that the Prefix does _not_ begin with a slash `/` and make sure that the named directory actually exists. You could test this by temporarily removing the Prefix parameter from the `list_objects_v2()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use `resource` methods rather than `client` methods. They will do pagination for you (to handle more than 1000 objects) and the functions are more Pythonic.

For example, you can count the files like this:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('BUCKET-NAME')

prefix = 'foo/'

count = 0

for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
    if object.key.endswith('/file_000.ts'):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Note that this example is using `endswith('/file_000.ts')` because the key of an object might look like this:

```
144p/something/file_000.ts
```